# Trying to Substitute an R base function by its parallel processing cousin (with trace function)

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, trace, mclapply

I'm trying to substitute **lapply** function with **mclapply** on a shiny application, with the trace function.

I'm trying to narrow the trace to the used package's namespace, but it is not working.

Most errors are problems of inputs in **lapply**, either by embedded function in **lapply** or more than one function as input.

EXAMPLE of Output:

```
Loading required package: shiny
Tracing function "lapply" in package "base"
Tracing lapply(paths, function(p) { .... on entry 
Error in lapply(X, FUN, ...) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
Tracing lapply(keys, get, missing) on entry 
Error in lapply(X, FUN, ...) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
Tracing lapply(x, f) on entry 
Tracing lapply(x, f) on entry
```

Here is how I'm calling **trace** function:

```
trace(base::lapply, tracer=substitute(parallel::mclapply(match.call())),where=namespace.vec)
```

and **namespace.vec** variable has the used packages namespaces used in the application.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `Tracing function "lapply" in package "base"` That is a supremely bad idea. You should always assume that your code somehow uses `lapply` internally and that you would create nested parallelization (which can be very problematic when not controlled carefully) by substituting it with `mclapply`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know this is an unorthodox way of doing it but do you happen to know or be able to suggest other options? Best